# Send data as Attachment to E-Mail without saving it on sd card

Tags: android, file, email, vcf-vcard

I am working on an application, where I am sending `.vcf` files to E-Mail as attachment thorugh my application,

I have used following code to achieve this,

```
try {
path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator +vfile;
FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
     mFileOutputStream.write(vCardString.toString().getBytes());
File filevcf = new File(path);
Log.d("file", "file" + filevcf);
} catch (Exception e4) {
Log.d("File", "File Error-->>" + e4);}
```

and I am using the following code to send this `.vcf` file to email using the default email application.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
String to[] = "asd@gmail.com";
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  Uri.parse(path));
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send email"));
```

In this case, I have to store the contact as `.vcf` file on the sd card and only then I am able to send it to email. in case, there is no sd card in the device, it throws excpetion.

I want the application to be able to send `.vcf` files even  if there is no sd card in the device. Is there any way to do this, or if there is any way to store this `.vcf` file somewhere else and then send it.

Comment: Have youtried internal storage? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Thanx, let me have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use internal storage to store your .vcf file and can delete once the server response is OK.